# Drupal fields internationalization

Tags: drupal

I want to create a new content type on Drupal with some new fields. These fields should be translatable which means having for one field many values for each available language. 
Now to display the node I want to display only the field values of the current language, the current language should be calculated from the url : 
/mysite.com/fr/produit_1  => show in Frensh
or
/mysite/en/my_product => show in English

Is that possible in Drupal even with custom development ? Which modules can I use to do that ?

Comment: Do you use *Content translation* module ?

Comment: I don't know the drupal module so that I'm asking for advice

Comment: I' haven't yet took my decision about that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use *Content translation* module (part of drupal core modules).

You can also take a look at [i18n](http://drupal.org/project/i18n) module.